Custom DNS resolver for HTTP Client request call over different IP route in Docker container using golang
I have a Docker container with multiple network namespaces.  Call them root, namespace1, namespace2.
The root container has an ENI attached to it, with connectivity to the public internet.
Namespace 1 has two veth pairs:
veth_pair1 - connected to namespace2 with ip address address123.  
veth_pair2 - connected to root with ip address234

In namespace 1, the ip route command shows:
default via address123 dev veth_pair1 (namespace2 ip address)
address234 dev veth_pair2

By default, traffic is routed over the default route through vethpair1 between namespace1 and namespace2.
What I want to do is under specific conditions, make http requests over the veth_pair2 (address234), while also using the DNS lookup server of the root namespace.
Following two posts:

https://koraygocmen.medium.com/custom-dns-resolver-for-the-default-http-client-in-go-a1420db38a5d
How to bind an http.Client in Go to an IP Address

I constructed a custom DNS http client bound to the local address to try and make HTTP requests from the namespace1 container over the veth_pair2 through root container.
localTCPAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "address234")
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("failed to resolve tcp local address with error %v", err)
}

log.Printf("using local tcp address with any port: %v", localTCPAddr)

dialer := &net.Dialer{
    Resolver: &net.Resolver{
        PreferGo: true,
        Dial: func(ctx context.Context, network, address string) (net.Conn, error) {
            d := net.Dialer{
                LocalAddr: &localTCPAddr,
                Timeout: time.Duration(5000) * time.Millisecond,
            }
            return d.DialContext(ctx, "tcp", "DNS server address")
        },
    },
}

dialContext := func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
    return dialer.DialContext(ctx, network, addr)
}
//
customHttpClient := &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        DialContext: dialContext,
    },
}

However, when the Docker container starts and the task to send the HTTP request out from the namespace1 over the root container gets called, I get the following error:
(Real addresses have been replaced with variables)
dial tcp: lookup #redactedURI on {DNS address}:
  dial tcp {localAddress}:80->{customDNSserverAddress}: bind: cannot assign requested address

It seems from my research that the address is unavailable.  But I've tried multiple iterations of the local address and ports, so I'm suspicious that it's a different setup problem.  Any ideas?

The variables obscure what's going on. Where are you running this and with which privileges?

this is running on a docker container but the code is platform code.  I assume the privileges are root privileges.  anything i can do in the description to make it more clear?

The actual Dockerfile and the actual output from Docker maybe?
